# Regex to consolidate multiple rules

Tags: java, regex, replace

I'm looking at optimising my string manipulation code and consolidating all of my `replaceAll`'s to just one pattern if possible

**Rules** -

- strip all special chars except `-`
- replace space with `-`
- condense consecutive `-` 's to just one `-`
- Remove leading and trailing `-`'s

**My code** -

```
public static String slugifyTitle(String value) {
    String slugifiedVal = null;
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value))
        slugifiedVal = value
                .replaceAll("[ ](?=[ ])|[^-A-Za-z0-9 ]+", "") // strips all special chars except -
                .replaceAll("\\s+", "-") // converts spaces to -
                .replaceAll("--+", "-"); // replaces consecutive -'s with just one -

    slugifiedVal = StringUtils.stripStart(slugifiedVal, "-"); // strips leading -
    slugifiedVal = StringUtils.stripEnd(slugifiedVal, "-"); // strips trailing -

    return slugifiedVal;
}
```

Does the job but obviously looks shoddy.

**My test assertions -**

```
Heading with symbols *~!@#$%^&()_+-=[]{};',.<>?/ ==> heading-with-symbols
    
Heading with an asterisk* ==> heading-with-an-asterisk
    
Custom-id-&-stuff ==> custom-id-stuff
    
--Custom-id-&-stuff-- ==> custom-id-stuff
```

Comment: It works and is readable. Why the need to reduce it? That would probably just make it less readable.

Comment: It does not work, `[^-A-Za-z0-9 ]` will remove a lot of chars including letters, as in my family name.

Comment: As a general comment, one should be aware that `String.replaceAll` compiles the regex each time it is invoked. You can pre-compile patterns and store them in a static field e.g. `static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("[ ](?=[ ])|[^-A-Za-z0-9 ]+"); static final Pattern p2 = ...`; then do `slugifiedVal = p1.matcher(slugifiedVal).replaceAll(""); slugifiedVal = p2.matcher(slugifiedVal).replaceAll("-");` at runtime. It separates the pattern and replacement, which isn't ideal, but it can make it run faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I don't think a regex approach to this problem is wrong, or that this is an objectively better approach. I am merely presenting an alternative approach as food for thought.

I have a tendency against regex approaches to problems where you have to *ask* how to solve with regex, because that implies you're going to struggle to maintain that solution in the future. There is an opacity to regexes where "just do this" is obvious, when you know just to do this.

Some problems typically solved with regex, like this one, can be solved using imperative code. It tends to be more verbose, but it uses simple, apparent, code constructs; it's easier to debug; and can be faster because it doesn't involve the full "machinery" of the regex engine.

---

```
static String slugifyTitle(String value) {
    boolean appendHyphen = false;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(value.length());

    // Go through value one character at a time...
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
      char c = value.charAt(i);

      if (isAppendable(c)) {
        // We have found a character we want to include in the string.

        if (appendHyphen) {
          // We previously found character(s) that we want to append a single
          // hyphen for.
          sb.append('-');
          appendHyphen = false;
        }
        sb.append(c);
      } else if (requiresHyphen(c)) {
        // We want to replace hyphens or spaces with a single hyphen.
        // Only append a hyphen if it's not going to be the first thing in the output.
        // Doesn't matter if this is set for trailing hyphen/whitespace,
        // since we then never hit the "isAppendable" condition.
        appendHyphen = sb.length() > 0;
      } else {
        // Other characters are simply ignored.
      }
    }

    // You can lowercase when appending the character, but `Character.toLowerCase()`
    // recommends using `String.toLowerCase` instead.
    return sb.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
}

// Some predicate on characters you want to include in the output.
static boolean isAppendable(char c) {
  return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
      || (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
}

// Some predicate on characters you want to replace with a single '-'.
static boolean requiresHyphen(char c) {
  return c == '-' || Character.isWhitespace(c);
}
```

(This code is wildly over-commented, for the purpose of explaining it in this answer. Strip out the comments and unnecessary things like the `else`, it's actually not super complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following regex parts:

- Any special chars other than `-`: `[\p{S}\p{P}&&[^-]]+` (character class subtraction)
- Any one or more whitespace or hyphens: `[^-\s]+` (this will be used to replace with a single `-`)
- You will still need to remove leading/trailing hyphens, it will be a separate post-processing step. If you wish, you can use a `^-+|-+$` regex.

So, you can only reduce this to three `.replaceAll` invocations keeping the code  precise and readable:

```java
public static String slugifyTitle(String value) {
    String slugifiedVal = null;
    if (value != null && !value.trim().isEmpty())
        slugifiedVal = value.toLowerCase()
                .replaceAll("[\\p{S}\\p{P}&&[^-]]+", "") // strips all special chars except -
                .replaceAll("[\\s-]+", "-") // converts spaces/hyphens to -
                .replaceAll("^-+|-+$", ""); // remove trailing/leading hyphens
    return slugifiedVal;
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/GWca4U):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Heading with symbols *~!@#$%^&()_+-=[]{};',.<>?/",
        "Heading with an asterisk*",
        "Custom-id-&-stuff",
        "--Custom-id-&-stuff--");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println("\"" + str + "\" => " + slugifyTitle(str));
}
```

Output:

```
"Heading with symbols *~!@#$%^&()_+-=[]{};',.<>?/" => heading-with-symbols
"Heading with an asterisk*" => heading-with-an-asterisk
"Custom-id-&-stuff" => custom-id-stuff
"--Custom-id-&-stuff--" => custom-id-stuff
```

**NOTE**: if your strings can contain any Unicode whitespace, replace `"[\\s-]+"` with `"(?U)[\\s-]+"`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and sharing your answer Wiktor, works like a charm. But i've decided to accept andy's answer just for the sake of maintainability and simplicity.
RegEx's have always been greek and latin to me :)

Comment: cool, i'll check it out, definitely need to gain some knowledge here